# Simple callback function for camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to get images from my camera without a previous.

Here is my **mainactivity.java**:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCamera = Camera.open();

        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

int j =2;
            public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
                // Process the contents of byte for whatever you need
                j++;
            }
        });

            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

            // Finds a suitable resolution.
            Size size= new Size(640,480);


            // Set-up camera size and video format. YCbCr_420_SP
            // should be the default on Android anyway.

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());

            parameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

            PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
            PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(mCamera.getParameters()
                    .getPreviewFormat(), pixelFormat);

            int sourceSize = size.getWidth() * size.getHeight()
                    * pixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
            mVideoSource = new byte[sourceSize];

            // Starts receiving pictures from the camera.
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
            mCamera.startPreview();    
    }
```

I don't understand why the program never pass through the PreviewCallback. In the variable the preview callback function seems to be well changed.

In fact I just want to grab image from my camera.

Edit:
Here is the modification I made from the link you gave me.

```
public class AGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private final AGLRenderer mRenderer;
    Camera mCamera;

    public AGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        mRenderer = new AGLRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);




    }

    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 3200;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
                    dx = dx * -1 ;
                }

                // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                if (x < getWidth() / 2) {
                    dy = dy * -1 ;
                }

                mRenderer.setAngle(mRenderer.getAngleX() + dy * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR,
                        mRenderer.getAngleY() + dx * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR);  // = 180.0f / 320
                requestRender();
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }

    public void setBackground(Bitmap b)
    {
        mRenderer.setBackground(b);
    }

    public void setAngle(float X,float Y,float Z)
    {
        mRenderer.setAngle(X,Y,Z);
        requestRender();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {



      int i = 1;
}
```

and the render

```
public class AGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static final String TAG = "AGLRenderer";
    private BackgroundTexture mBackgroundTexture;
    private SquareTexture mSquareTexture;
    private Square mSquare;

    // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrixlX = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrixlY = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrixX = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrixY = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrixZ = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix0 = new float[16];

    float angleX ,angleY ,angleZ ;
    private float mAngleX;
    private float mAngleY;

    Context localcontext;
    public AGLRenderer(Context context) {
        super();
        localcontext = context;
    }


    public void setAngle(float X,float Y,float Z)
    {
        angleX = X;
        angleY = Y;
        angleZ = Z;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {


        angleX = 0;
        angleY = 0;
        angleZ = 0;

        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        mSquareTexture = new SquareTexture(localcontext);
        mSquare = new Square();
        mBackgroundTexture = new BackgroundTexture(localcontext);
        mBackgroundTexture.loadTexture();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        float[] scratch = new float[16];

        // Draw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix0, 0, angleX, 0, 1.0f, 0);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrixX, 0, angleX, 0, 1,0);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrixY, 0, angleY, 0, 0,1);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrixZ, 0, angleZ, 1, 0,0);

//        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
//        {
//          for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
//            {
//              Log.d("tt"," "+(mRotationMatrix0[j*4+i]));
//            }
//        }
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix0, 0,mRotationMatrixY , 0,  mRotationMatrixZ, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix0, 0,mRotationMatrix0 , 0,  mRotationMatrixX, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix, 0,mRotationMatrix0  , 0, mViewMatrix , 0);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

        // Draw square
        //mSquareTexture.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        //mBackgroundTexture.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
        // such as screen rotation
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 50);

    }

    /**
     * Utility method for compiling a OpenGL shader.
     *
     * <p><strong>Note:</strong> When developing shaders, use the checkGlError()
     * method to debug shader coding errors.</p>
     *
     * @param type - Vertex or fragment shader type.
     * @param shaderCode - String containing the shader code.
     * @return - Returns an id for the shader.
     */
    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);


        return shader;
    }

    /**
    * Utility method for debugging OpenGL calls. Provide the name of the call
    * just after making it:
    *
    * <pre>
    * mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    * AGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");</pre>
    *
    * If the operation is not successful, the check throws an error.
    *
    * @param glOperation - Name of the OpenGL call to check.
    */
    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the rotation angle of the triangle shape (mTriangle).
     *
     * @return - A float representing the rotation angle.
     */
    public float getAngleX() {
        return mAngleX;
    }
    public float getAngleY() {
        return mAngleY;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the rotation angle of the triangle shape (mTriangle).
     */
    public void setAngle(float angleX,float angleY) {
        mAngleX = angleX;
        mAngleY = angleY;

    }

    public void setBackground(Bitmap background)
    {
        mBackgroundTexture.loadTexture(background);
    }

}
```

I have the preview of my camera on the GLSurfaceView but the program don't go anymore through the onSurfaceCreated, ondrawframe, of the GLSurfaceView.Renderer. How can this be possible?

In fact my goal is to diplay the camera images and be able to draw 3d object above it.

Edit:

I found a other program here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



 GLSurfaceView glView;
    CameraView cameraView;
    GLClearRenderer clearRenderer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // When working with the camera, it's useful to stick to one orientation.
        setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );

        // Next, we disable the application's title bar...
        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        // ...and the notification bar. That way, we can use the full screen.
        getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

        // Now let's create an OpenGL surface.
        glView = new GLSurfaceView( this );
        // To see the camera preview, the OpenGL surface has to be created translucently.
        // See link above.
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser( 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0 );
        glView.getHolder().setFormat( PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT );
        // The renderer will be implemented in a separate class, GLView, which I'll show next.
        clearRenderer = new GLClearRenderer();
        glView.setRenderer( clearRenderer );
        // Now set this as the main view.
        setContentView( glView );

        // Now also create a view which contains the camera preview...
        cameraView = new CameraView( this );
        // ...and add it, wrapping the full screen size.
        addContentView( cameraView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams( ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
    }

    public class GLClearRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

        private BackgroundTexture mBackgroundTexture;
        private SquareTexture mSquareTexture;
        private Square mSquare;

        // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
        private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
        private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
        private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrixlX = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrixlY = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrixX = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrixY = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrixZ = new float[16];
        private final float[] mRotationMatrix0 = new float[16];

        float angleX ,angleY ,angleZ ;
        private float mAngleX;
        private float mAngleY;

        public void onDrawFrame( GL10 gl ) {
            // This method is called per frame, as the name suggests.
            // For demonstration purposes, I simply clear the screen with a random translucent gray.
            float c = 1.0f / 256 * ( System.currentTimeMillis() % 256 );
            GLES20.glClearColor( c, c, c, 0.5f );
            GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

            // Draw background color
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


            // Set the camera position (View matrix)
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            // Calculate the projection and view transformation
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

            // Draw square
            mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix); %%%%%%% NOT DISPLAY
        }


        public void onSurfaceChanged( GL10 gl, int width, int height ) {
            // This is called whenever the dimensions of the surface have changed.
            // We need to adapt this change for the GL viewport.
            GLES20.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

            float ratio = (float) width / height;

            // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
            // in the onDrawFrame() method
            Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 50);
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated( GL10 gl, EGLConfig config ) {
            // No need to do anything here.

            angleX = 0;
            angleY = 0;
            angleZ = 0;

            // Set the background frame color
            //GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            mSquare = new Square(); %%%%%%% NOT DISPLAY

        }
    }

    public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private Camera camera;

        public CameraView( Context context ) {
            super( context );
            // We're implementing the Callback interface and want to get notified
            // about certain surface events.
            getHolder().addCallback( this );
            // We're changing the surface to a PUSH surface, meaning we're receiving
            // all buffer data from another component - the camera, in this case.
            getHolder().setType( SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
        }

        public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
            // Once the surface is created, simply open a handle to the camera hardware.
            camera = Camera.open();
        }

        public void surfaceChanged( SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height ) {
            // This method is called when the surface changes, e.g. when it's size is set.
            // We use the opportunity to initialize the camera preview display dimensions.
            Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize( width, height );
            //camera.setParameters( p );

            // We also assign the preview display to this surface...
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay( holder );
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // ...and start previewing. From now on, the camera keeps pushing preview
            // images to the surface.
            camera.startPreview();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
            // Once the surface gets destroyed, we stop the preview mode and release
            // the whole camera since we no longer need it.
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }


}
```

The blinking of the screen works but the square that I use is not display. I don't understand why.

Comment: means you want live camera Preview.on any view...like imageView....???

Comment: I want to take pictures from my camera a show them into my main glview

Comment: using any click event..or without..?

Comment: My GLSurfaceiew get its on onTouchEvent

Comment: @ Xavier BuC...the grafica project provided by...@Ambuj Kathotiya...is works properly....i did use it on myCameraApp..which is completed today.

Comment: Rellay plz look deeply on grafica..that will do helps to you...and  also check out my asked question. related to camera on my profile.

Comment: The grafica works properly sorry. Is here a example of preview camera in glview?

Comment: now i am going to my Home and i am already late...but you will do comment tomorrow i will tell you..if i have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this thread for how to create a preview class to display the camera preview in the same activity -
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: The problem is that I use a GLsurfaceView  mGLView = new AGLSurfaceView(this);        setContentView(mGLView);

Comment: Check if this is of any help -
 https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java and http://nhenze.net/?p=172

Comment: Thank you but the project don't seems to work properly.